# Installing mtpro2 with mactex on os x sierra

Tags: errors, installing, mac, mtpro

I'm trying to install `mtpro2` fonts.

I followed directions on 
http://www.pctex.com/kb/74.html

Here's what happened. Any suggestions?

```
Brians-iMac:~ brianhons$ sudo texhash

Password:

texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/ls-R... 

texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/ls-R... 

texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/ls-R...

texhash: Updating /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/ls-R... 

texhash: Done.

Brians-iMac:~ brianhons$ sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=mtpro2.map

updmap [WARNING]: resetting $HOME value (was /Users/brianhons) to root's actual home (/var/root).

updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg

updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg

Creating new config file /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg

dvips output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"

pdftex output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"

dvipdfmx output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap"

updmap [ERROR]: The following map file(s) couldn't be found:

updmap [ERROR]:     mtpro2.map (in /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)

updmap [ERROR]: Did you run mktexlsr?

    You can disable non-existent map entries using the option
      --syncwithtrees.
```

Comment: In which directory is the file `mtpro2.map` located? If it's in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/dvips/mtpro2`or in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/map/dvips/mtpro2`, try switching to one of those directories and re-running `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=mtpro2.map`.

Comment: It's in usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/mtpro2.

Comment: I changed directories and it did not work.

updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.
updmap: Updating ls-R files.

Comment: Would the fact that I still have 2015basic as well as 2016 installed be causing problems.  In the directory, 2015basic, 2016, and texmf-local are at the same level.  All the mtpro2 files are in texmf-local.

Comment: I guess it depends on how you've set up the path variables. Is  your system running only MacTeX2016 at present -- and not MacTeX2015?

Comment: Just MacTeX2016.

Comment: What, if anything, is currently in `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg`?

Comment: The only file in the web2c folder is updmap.cfg

Comment: Yes, and what's *inside* that file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59527/discussion-between-b-h-and-mico).